# Did not find frame. when using Agora video calling in flutter can't see frame of caller and from caller device can't see receivers frame

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

In this video call can't see other person and getting error of did not find frame:

[image]

I was trying to add video calling feature and hosted token server in node js and ui is in dart .

```dart
Future<void> initialize({String? tokenUrl, String? channelName}) async {
    if (_client == null) {
      _client = AgoraClient(
        agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
          appId: AgoraConfig.agoraAppId,
          channelName: channelName!,
          tokenUrl: tokenUrl,
        ),
      );
      await _client!.initialize();
    }
  }
```

this is my code for initialising agora io